# Migrate existing safe to goerli in order to write to a contract

Tags: etherscan, goerli

i have an existing safe, and the address was used to deploy a contract on goerli. i need to write to that contract, but the safe is only recognized on eth mainnet. currently i am the only signer on the safe.